# MongoDB AND operator in match aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get from the below collection the books where their publisher is not the one with the `id :61f27f1267308604f233c103` and the `status` is `unpublished`.
I am trying to do that using the `"$and"` operator I am not sure if there is a better approach.

Books collection:

```
{
    _id: '61f27f1267308604f233c200',
    category: 'comic',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f233c103',
    status: 'unpublished'
},
{
    _id: '61f12f1267308604f239d002',
    category: 'comic',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f288dt88',
    status: 'unpublished'
},
{
    _id: '61f12f1267308604f233u873',
    category: 'comic',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f233c103',
    status: 'published'
},
{
    _id: '61f12f1267308604f233c773',
    category: 'education',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f277c103',
    status: 'published'
},

{
    _id: '61f12f1267308604f233c103',
    category: 'comic',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f233c103',
    status: 'published'
},

{
    _id: '61f12f1267308604f239i002',
    category: 'comic',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f288dt88',
    status: 'published'
},
{
    _id: '61f12f1267308604f239i002',
    category: 'comic',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f288du73',
    status: 'published'
},
```

The query I wrote, I could replace the `"$in"` with `"$exists" :true` but there is a possibility where specific publishers selected from the relevant filter.

```
  db.books.find( { $and : [ 
    {'publisherId' : { $in : ['61f27f1267308604f288dt88','61f27f1267308604f288du73','61f27f1267308604f233c103']}},
    { $and : [
        {'publisherId' : { $nin : ['61f27f1267308604f277c103']}},
        {'status' :'unpublished'}]]}} )
```

The expected result should be:

```
{
    _id: '61f12f1267308604f233c773',
    category: 'education',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f277c103',
    status: 'published'
},
{
    _id: '61f12f1267308604f233c103',
    category: 'comic',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f233c103',
    status: 'published'
},
{
    _id: '61f12f1267308604f239d002',
    category: 'comic',
    author: 115,
    publisherId: '61f27f1267308604f288dt88',
    status: 'unpublished'
},
```

but I get nothing.

Comment: In your Collection you only have one document with status unpublished and the publisherId is exactly the one you put in the $nin operator, the query is working as you expect but you don't have any document that matches the criteria

Comment: @DavidSN But I still need the books from the same publisher with the published status. I do not get those.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simplify your query, as `,` is a native separator between `and` conditions:

```
db.collection.find({
  "publisherId": {$nin: ["61f27f1267308604f277c103"]},
  "status": "unpublished"
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0t9t_o9SzsH)

But this is useful if publisherId is not allowed to be any value from a list. If the list contains only one value, you can repalce it with `$ne`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "publisherId": {$ne: "61f27f1267308604f277c103"},
  "status": "unpublished"
})
```

Which will give you the same resutlt.

**Edit**:
If you want the opposite, as implied in your comment, just use:

```
db.collection.find({
  "publisherId": "61f27f1267308604f233c103",
  "status": {$ne: "unpublished"}
})
```

Which will return your new expected results:

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yot3jfkA7hD)

**Another edit:**
If you want to exclude only books that are both with `status: unpublished` and from `publisherId: "61f27f1267308604f277c103"}`, which is a NAND gate, you can use:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {publisherId: {$ne: "61f27f1267308604f277c103"}},
    {status: {$ne: "unpublished"}}
  ]
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example - NAND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t0rhaPz3zvn)

Comment: I modified the expected results.

Comment: But you said you want status "unpublished", and you results are with status 'published'...same for the publisherId

Comment: updated the answer accordingly

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I updated the question again. Basically, what I want to succeed is to exclude the books where certain publishers have status unpublished. However for the same publisher I still need the books with status published.

Comment: Still unclear. Please explain for each of 3 document in the expected output, why it is returned

Comment: The first two results I get them because their publisherId is in the $in array and third because its also in the $in array, I only want to exclude the books with unpublished status from the 61f27f1267308604f277c103 publisher.

Comment: So you should have many more results....

Comment: updated the answer accordingly again